# Panel Move Everytime on Button Click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, move

I’m using WinForms. In my Form I have a panel and a button.

Goal: Every time I click on the button I want the panel to move up.

Issue: The problem I’m currently having is that the panel only moves up only once.

```
    private void Button_Up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Location.Y != 250)
        {
            while (panel1.Location.Y > 250)
            {
                panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y - 80);

            }
        }

        else  
        {
            if (panel1.Location.Y < 1000)
            {
                while (panel1.Location.Y > 10)
                {
                    panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y - 80);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your while-loops will keep moving the panel until it satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `while` makes it move as much as it can.

Subsequent clicks will find that `panel1.Location.Y` is already <= to `10` so they won't update its location.

You don't need that `while`.

Comment: I removed the second while, but the panel still moves only once.

Answer (score 1):

Did you debug your code? According to your code, it's moving to it's final location where the condition is met.
After that, each time it enters the first 'if', as the value is not 250 (but less), so the else is ignored and nothing happens.

you probable want just 1 check, if the Y is not less that the height of the panel, than move up by 80 as per your values.